# How to resolve a target class which doesn't exist?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm following an Auth API laravel tutorial from a website. I'm testing the endpoints with Postman where I am consistently getting this error.

"Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController] does not exist.",

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM773.png)

[RegisterController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT6Ba.png)

[Api.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXYop.png)

Sorry I can't edit images, just links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `RegisterController` is missing namespace.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
```

Comment: thx to your answer. I'm beginning to Laravel and I don't see this mistake

Comment: if that solves the issue, mark the answer as accepted :)